# What's the easiest way of installing JRE on Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, java

What is the easiest way of installing JRE on my Debian OS (Linux)?

Comment: what do you consider easy, does `sudo apt-get install java6-jre` isn't easy enough ?

Comment: @kiwy Debian doesn't have a package named `java6-jre`.

Comment: @jordanm yes OK but it wasz an example the package is indeed  `openjdk-7-jre` or `openjdk-6-jre` or even `sun-java6-jre` but still this question shows a very limited understanding and search quality

Comment: I edited the title to be more Debian-specific. Oracle actually publishes RPM packages for RedHat-based distros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the version of the language and the version of the implementation you're after.

### Sun/Oracle JRE

Sun used to provide .deb packages for Java 6 that where present in Debian's official packages. So installing it was pretty straightforward:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

However they do not provide deb packages for Java 7. They do provide, however binary packages you can install like this:

```
wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7/jdk-7-linux-x64.tar.gz
tar zxvf jdk-7-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/lib64/jvm/
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin/java 1065
```

Alternatively, you can look for user-supplied repos that provide a .deb packages (trust these at your own risk, since it's not officially supported by Debian). You can add this repo ([source](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-debian.html)):

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886
apt-get update
```

Installing Java 7 becomes straightforward:

```
apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

### OpenJDK

OpenJDK is an open source implementation of the Java language specification and it's available in the Debian repository. You can install it with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Comment: +1 My preference is to let the distro install and manage the default `openJDK` and then install Oracle into it's own directory, adding Oracle's `bin/` to the beginning of `$PATH` so the system prefers it (no use of `update-alternatives`).  Easy to switch back and forth if you have some reason to do so, and the two installations will not conflict with one another.

Answer (score 2):

Install the Debian package, using Debian's tools:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Only in very unusual circumstances does it make any sense to do otherwise.

Comment: @terdon Why would you recommend Java 6 instead of 7?

Comment: @n.st no good reason whatsoever, I just copy/pasted jordanm's comment to the OP, thanks, I fixed my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a Debian package for Sun's JRE by using the make-jpkg utility in the `java-package` package. However, Debian of course discourages this and recommends OpenJDK.